Error: Redirect URI Mismatch when Integrating Microsoft Authentication with Django
I am trying to integrate Microsoft authentication with my Django app deployed on Azure Web App using the django_auth_adfs package. However, I encountered an error regarding a mismatch in the redirect URI.
I have followed the documentation provided by django_auth_adfs for configuring Azure Active Directory integration. In my Azure portal, I registered the application and added http://localhost:8000/oauth2/callback to the Web Redirect URLs as instructed.
Web Redirect URLs
When attempting to authenticate, I receive the following error message:
The redirect URI 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/callback' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal.

Here is my settings.py configuration related to django_auth_adfs:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_auth_adfs',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django_auth_adfs.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAccessTokenBackend',
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = 'django_auth_adfs:login' 
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# django-auth-adfs settings
AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': config('MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
    'CLIENT_ID': config('MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
    'CLIENT_SECRET': config('MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name', 'last_name': 'family_name', 'email': 'upn'},
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles', # or None
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'upn',
    'TENANT_ID': config('MICROSOFT_AUTH_TENANT_ID'),
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': config('MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
}
ADFS_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/oauth2/callback'

What could be causing this redirect URI mismatch error despite configuring the correct redirect URI in the Azure portal? Is there anything additional I need to configure or check within my Django or Azure settings to resolve this issue?
Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

_Enthusiast Chage the 127.0.0.1 this value to localhost in browser.

Or Use this Command python manage.py runserver localhost:8000 to run the application.

Even I faced the same error code as yours, In order to resolve the error, Refer the steps below.
I used the command below to run the Application.
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
This helped me get the URL with localhost instead of the following URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000.
Below is Settings. py code.
settings. py:
from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.paren
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pnoikqzon+<Key>'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_auth_adfs',
    'api',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'django_auth_adfs.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoAd.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoAd.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAuthCodeBackend',
)
LOGIN_URL = "django_auth_adfs:login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('client_secret')
tenant_id = os.getenv('tenant_id')
AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': client_id,
    'CLIENT_ID': client_id,
    'CLIENT_SECRET': client_secret,
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name',
                      'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn'},
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles',
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'upn',
    'TENANT_ID': tenant_id,
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': client_id,
}

After app registration, I added http://localhost:8000/oauth2/callback to the Web Redirect URLs, as shown below.

I have added the optional claims below to the token configuration.

After running the application, I received the following, and I chose my account.

I accepted the app registration, as shown below.

Output:


Thank you very much, it worked. However I have a question, does this also work in a production environment? Or in Web Redirect URLs should I add my-site.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/callback ?

@LLM_Enthusiast you need add this url  my-site.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/callback to Web redirect in App Registration for production.

I included the URL in the App Registration, but since the redirect URLs only accept HTTPS, Django generates an HTTP URL in the request. How can I resolve this issue?

I solved adding this in settings.py: SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True and SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
